# Lithium Air vs Li Fluoride battery capacity

Tags: redox, energy, metal, halides, reduction-potential

Lithium air aka lithium oxygen batteries are described as highest theoretical capacity battery possible. In wikipedia, it says lithium air has energy density 5210 Watt hour per kg, including weight of the oxygen.

What if we used  fluorine instead of oxygen? Obviously, voltage would go up since fluorine is more electronegative than oxygen but when it comes to energy to weight ratio, I am not so sure if it will be better.

Fluorine is element number number 9 and oxygen 8, that means its heavier by one proton and one neutron, furthermore it can take only one electron as opposed to the oxygen which can accept two so you need twice as many atoms to make the reaction.

With all that said, which one is the true ultimate theoretical combination. What is the theoretical energy density of lithium fluorine battery in watt hours per kg?

Comment: What is your supposed theoretical arrangement of such a battery, considering fluorine reactivity?

Comment: @Poutnik There is no arrangement, theoretical maximum capacity does not take arrangement into consideration. Its like 100% carnot efficiency, or energy density of fuel material, its just a value that cannot be ever exceeded. Go into wikipedia "metal air battery" page and you will find bunch of these values, hydrocarbons have similiar values too, only difference is that they use mega joule per kilogram instead of kWh/kg.

Comment: Even theoretical analysis must take into account the theoretical considerations. The is no point in considering theoretical potentials when everything would blow up or if the whole cell burns in contact with fluorine. To consider specific energy, you have to evaluate the particular electrochemical system.

Comment: @Poutnik No, you are wrong. This isnt even theoretical analysis, its maximum theoretical energy. Whether it blow up instantly is irrelevant in same way as you will never extract 120 mega joules out of kilogram of hydrogen in heat engine. Yet 120 MJ/kg is still number that is usefull, despite being unrealistic to attain in any system of any possible arrangement.

Comment: I insist that to consider specific energy, you have to evaluate the particular electrochemical system, as it is not only about the storage capacity but also voltage. And regarding specific storage capacity, the molar masses of involved active substances must be known as well.

Comment: @Poutnik I think you misunderstood my question, I again suggest you look at the "metal air battery" wikipedia page. Voltage is always lower in real battery, especially as it depletes than theoretical electrode redox voltage. The value I am asking about, the maximum theoretical Joule/kg or watt hour/kg, does NOT take into consideration REAL world, realistic, attainable voltage in system of given arrangement. You are thinking in realistic values, like those we get from real batteries, but this is completly different value that is calculated in completly different way than what I am asking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129146/discussion-between-poutnik-and-soliton).

Comment: @Soliton. It is no use reasoning like you do. Fluorine is a gas that reacts with everything. Water is destroyed in presence o fluorine. Plastics are destroyed. Metals are destroyed. Sometimes violently, with flames. The only substance that does not react with fluorine are the fluorides, which can be considered as the ashes produced by the action of fluorine. You may imagine cells with fluorine. They will never be working ! Never !

Comment: @Maurice And despite all of that, you can still calculate theoretical energy density of Lithium - Fluorine battery, isnt that amazing? The calculation doesnt care if its possible in real world, only how much energy it has.

Comment: @Soliton. You could also calculate the theoretical pressure of a gas contained in a $1$ liter flask containing $10^{100}$ kg at a temperature of $10^{100}$ K. I am sure this calculation is possible.